# Magento 2 The session id is too long

Tags: magento2, session

I am running Magento 2.2 on php7.1 and getting the following errors in my var/report and on my error log:

```
>     {"0":"Warning: SessionHandler::read(): The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and
> '-,' in \/home\/home1\/public_html\/vendor\/magent
>     o\/framework\/Session\/SaveHandler\/Native.php on line 22","1":"#0 [internal function]: Magento\\Framework\\App\\ErrorHandler->handler(2,
> 'SessionHandler:...', '\/
```

Comment: I have a few of these popping up, did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: i dont think so - just forgot about it and moved on....

Comment: Im wondering if its just attackers trying to force an error as can possible show vulnerable information in the warning https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185779/the-session-id-is-too-long-or-contains-illegal-characters-valid-characters-are